# Get running instance of Ace editor defined in other file

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I initialise Ace editor as follows

```
var editor = ace.edit("editor");
```

However, in another file I make changes to the value of that editor. How do I target that editor without creating a new one? In other words, if the above code is in `scripts.js` and I need to change the value of `editor` with `.setValue()` from another file that's loaded later, let's say `edit.js`, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the scope of your `editor` variable.

If this is a global variable you should just be able to continue using

**scripts.js**

```
var editor = ace.edit("editor");
```

**edit.js**

```
editor != 'undefined'
```

The only thing you need to think about is the order of execution - For example, if the `edit.js` file is loaded before (or gets executed before) the `scripts.js` file, then your global variable may not have been defined yet

Comment: But what if it isn't a global variable? It's quite unlikely that two different files share such a global variable, as the editor can only initialise on document ready, which limits the scope of the variable in the one file.

Comment: @BramVanroy You don't show enough code for me to guess how you've put together your solution. Just because it is initialised in `onready` doesn't mean that the variable isn't global